# XML Schema - Element attribute with different datatypes (need a simple typ definition)

Tags: xml, schema

I have a question about XML-Schema. 
I want to check if my XML element attribute has the following appearance and want to do this with an empty XML element with only one attribute.

---

```
<OtherElement Id="OE-1">
 ...
</OtherElement>
<MyElement MyAttribute="OE-1 10.0 2.0 12.3 string"/>
```

---

MyAttribute needs a simple type like this.

MyAttribute = "IDREF DOUBLE DOUBLE DOUBLE"

Is this possible for a attribute or it is necessary to create a complex typ and use a XML element with content?

I hoped this Schema will work but it doesn't.

```
<simpleType name="SampleTypeUnion">
 <union memberTypes="test:BookRef test:DoubListRest"/>
</simpleType>

<simpleType name="BookRef">
 <restriction base="IDREF"/>
</simpleType>

<simpleType name="DoubListRest">
 <restriction base="test:DoubList">
  <length value="3"/>
 </restriction>
</simpleType>

<simpleType name="DoubList">
 <list itemType="test:Doub"/>
</simpleType>

<simpleType name="Doub">
 <restriction base="double"/>
</simpleType>
```

Thanks at all for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with XSD 1.1, provided you are concerned with validation only, and not with data typing (though I'm not at all sure it is a good design).

You can define the type as a list of `xs:TOKEN` with a length facet constraining the number of tokens that appears, and then you can constrain the type of individual tokens with assertions of the form

```
<xs:assert test="$value[3] castable as xs:double"/>
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Kay,

thanks for you're help.
Is there an open source XSD editor that supports XSD 1.1?

Comment: I've no idea. I use oXygen.

Answer (score -1):

What you a looking for is XML Schema list Element.
Check it out here:
[[https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_list.asp][1](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_list.asp)](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_list.asp)
and here:
http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema1/chapter11.html

Comment: The OP appears to know about the `xs:list` element, but wants a way to apply different constraints to different items in the list.